# What version of Node do I Need for Webdriver.Io?

Tags: node.js, testing, webdriver-io

Just need clarification on this,
But what version of Node do I need to run Webdriver.io?
I'm currently restricted to using v 0.10.26 of Node and wondering can i use Webdriver.io 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node 0.12+ according the [webdriverio package.json](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/package.json#L19-L21).

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.12.0"
  },
```